# YADCF - filtering using hidden columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yadcf

Going through this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emLfa5s0/6/), I wanted to know the YADCF equivalent of hidden columns, as shown in use for the standard [DataTables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html), to enable for filtering from hidden columns (DataTable's targets seems to be equivalent to YADCF's column number).

Below is the code I have for a table where I want to hide the first column,
 yet still allow filtering from it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  'use strict';
  var foodTable = $('#foodTable').DataTable({
  });
  yadcf.init(foodTable, [{
      column_number: 0,
      filter_type: "select",
      visible: "false"
    },
    {
      column_number: 1,
      filter_type: "select"
    }
  ], {
    cumulative_filtering: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/yadcf/0.9.1/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"></script>
<table id="foodTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Subtype</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fruit</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>Fuji</td>
      <td>Very sweet apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vegetable</td>
      <td>Pumpkin</td>
      <td>Butternut</td>
      <td>Very fibrous pumpkin</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the filter of the hidden column out side of the table, for that purpose you can use `filter_container_id` (read docs)

for example

```
yadcf.init(oTable, [{
    column_number: 0,
    filter_container_id: "myId",
    column_data_type: "html",
    filter_type: "multi_select"
},{
    column_number: 1,
    filter_type: "multi_select"
}], "footer");
```

[See working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/3kvc1pp9/1/)

```
<div id="myId">
</div>
```

As to the *cumulative_filtering* you should use more recent version of yadcf (see change log)

Comment: Thanks. One thing - is there a way to still keep the hidden column's name, even though the column itself is not being shown?

Comment: that question should be pointer to datatables author / forum although I'm not sure how good that idea is... I might look bad or result in a bad UX

Comment: I was thinking of trying it out with 2 columns hidden, which would require labelling of the 2 dropdowns to distinguish between them.